# Android - how to specify special attribute to some specific view in different theme

Tags: android, styles, android-theme

I am working on a "dynamic change theme" function of my app (light and dark).

I have some special customized widget which is using special color. And I also want to specify the color of this widget in theme attributes.

For example, I want to set an attribute in the theme like

```
<item name="MySpecialTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

In the layout, how can I set the text color of the TextView?

```
<TextView
...
android:color="XXXX????"
...
/>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define two colors in `/res/values/colors.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <!-- ActionBar-->
    <color name="MySpecialTextColorLight">@color/white</color>
    <color name="MySpecialTextColorDark">@color/black</color>
<resources>
```

Then define an attribute with a unique name in `/res/values/attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="mytheme_text_color" format="color"/>
</resources>
```

Next, define value for this attribute in your two themes, like:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="mytheme_text_color">@color/MySpecialTextColorDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.Light" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="mytheme_text_color">@color/MySpecialTextColorLight</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Finally, use the reference attribute you define to refer to these colors. In your case, you use:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:color="?attr/mytheme_text_color"
    .../>
```

Comment: Great! I will try and feedback later.

Comment: Hi, some update. It seems that ?attr/xxx cannot be used in selectors, any idea?

Comment: @Robin Instead of selectors with styled attributes you can use two different drawable resources, for example `/drawable/btn_bg_light.xml` and `/drawable/btn_bg_dark.xml`. Then define attribute `<attr name="mytheme_button_bg" format="reference"/>` and define its value for each theme. In case of light theme: `<item name="mytheme_button_bg">@drawable/btn_bg_light</item>`. Now you can use this attribute, like: `<Button ... android:background="?attr/mytheme_button_bg"/>`.

Comment: What should I say... Your help saved me several hours of time. But I cannot thank you more. More up vote to your other answers. Thanks a lot my friend.